# Logical or statements

Tags: logic

If there is a logical or statement, for example $a\vee b\vee c$, is the requirement that only one of $a$, $b$, or $c$ must be true for the statement $a\vee b\vee c$ to be true?

Comment: As a side note, remember this is a binary operation, so $a\lor b\lor c$ really means $(a\lor b)\lor c.$ If $\lor$ really meant “exactly one is true,” then $(a\lor b)\lor c$ would be true if exactly one of the three was true, but it would also be true if all three of them were true. This is because if $a,b,c$ are all true, then $a\lor b$ would be false, and thus exactly one of $a\lor b$ or $c$ would be true. There is no way to define $x\lor y$ so that $(a\lor b)\lor c$ means exactly one of them is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be clear: It means that **at least** one among the three needs to be true for the disjunction to be true.